# Не получается сравнить переменную double с числом double(java)

Tags: java, double

Имеется метод для Robocode который получает массив double с 2 координатами(X Y соответственно) , метод нужен для случаев когда в координаты попадают отрицательные значения / значения вышедшие за пределы сетки. По какой то причине условия в первом и третьем if всегда выдают "true" из-за чего сбивается коррекция

```
public double[] correction(double mas[]) {

    System.out.println("Получил массив с координатами X = " + mas[0] + " и Y = " + mas[1]);
    double x = Math.rint(mas[0]); - пробовал
    double y = Math.rint(mas[1]);
    if (x - 18 < 0) {
        mas[0] = 18.0;
    }
    if (x > (getWidth() - 18.0)) {
        mas[0] = getWidth() - 18.0;
    }
    if (y - 18 < 0) {
        mas[1] = 18.0;
    }
    if (y > (getHeight() - 18.0)) {
        mas[1] = getHeight() - 18.0;
    }
    System.out.println("Вернул массив с координатами X = " + mas[0] + " и Y = " + mas[1]);
    return mas;
}
```

Пробовал привести к int и сравнивать уже int цифры - не помогло. Как то вот так:

```
int x = (int) Math.rint(mas[0]); - пробовал
int y = (int) Math.rint(mas[1]);
```

Какие бы не были координаты - они ВСЕГДА на выходе получают по 18.0
Примеры консолей выводят вот это:
"Получил массив с координатами X = 18.0 и Y = 566.0
Вернул массив с координатами X = 18.0 и Y = 18.0"

Собственно что не так?

Comment: ************UPD
А вот если я вывожу в отдельный класс , делаю метод статическим и вызываю его то все норм. Ну что за фигня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему проблема не с первым и третьим условием, а со вторым и четвертым. Воспользуйтесь отладчиком для анализа состояния переменных и объекта в контексте которого выполняется код. В частности проверьте что возвращают `getHeight()` и `getWidth()`. Вместо отладчика можно ввести в условие вывод на консоль подставив в тело второго и четвертого условий `System.out.println((getWidth() - 18.0)` и  `System.out.println((getHeight() - 18.0)` соответственно.

Comment: Да. Таки вместо метода getWidth() надо было вызывать метод getBattleFieldWidth()
Всем спасибо. Я идиот. Тему можно закрывать :)